# How can I configure an unlocked HTC Sensation XE for 3g connectivity in USA?

Tags: 3g, sim-unlocking, htc-sensation-xe

I bought this phone in India and brought it home to USA. In India I had no issues in connecting to 3G network but after coming back to USA I am no longer able to connect to 3G network (AT&T). I know the phone operates in a different frequency but I wanted to know if there is a way to tweak this.

I got excited when I saw a similar [link](http://androidforums.com/samsung-galaxy-s/258859-how-enable-850mhz-3g-network-frequency-your-samsung-i9000-galaxy-s.html) posted on another forum but that did not work on my phone.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AT&T's [3G](http://www.att.com/gen/press-room?pid=14003) works in the 1900 MHz and 850 MHz frequencies.

Even though [HTC Sensation XE](http://www.gsmarena.com/htc_sensation_xe-4164.php) is listed as supporting the 850 MHz frequency, it is only using it for slower 2G (EDGE) speeds.  For 3G it's using T-Mobile's HSDPA bands 900/1700/2100 MHz.  Unfortunately no amount of tweaking in the phone's software will make it work on AT&T's 3G bands, since this is a hardware difference in the phone's modem.

There are very few phones that work on both T-Mobile and AT&T's 3G frequencies - those are called "penta-band".  The new Samsung Galaxy Nexus is one of them, along with older Nokia models E7, N8 and N9 phones, for example.

Comment: Fun fact, the T-Mobile Vibrant only uses 1700/1900/2100 for 3G and works on AT&T as well.  It's quadband 2G though.

Comment: Interesting!  I haven't seen other phones that are in both 1700/2100 AND 1900 3G frequencies.  Do we have a community wiki question on carrier bands for 2G/3G/4G?  If not, we should definitely start one up.

Comment: So that I understand it correctly... If I change my service to T-Mobile I might get 3G speeds on my phone.

Comment: @logik6 Yes, you should be able to get 3G speeds on T-Mobile.  I would suggest trying a friend's T-Mobile SIM card or walking into a T-Mobile store and asking them to confirm by using one of their cards.